# EASY C Max Array Element program -> CANNOT find/understand the error

Tags: c, arrays, max

I have written this program which finds the index of the largest element, in an array of integers. For some reason I am getting the following errors when I try compiling it. Any ideas on what is wrong with my code? I cannot seem to find anything.

```
part1.c:9: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant

part1.c: In function ‘main’:

part1.c:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘largest’

part1.c: At top level:

part1.c:20: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
make: *** [part1] Error 1
```

My Code:

```
// Program that finds the largest element in an array of integers 

#include <stdio.h>

// Main body
// Create and initialise a one-dimensional array of integers

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
int largest(int array, int ARRAY_SIZE);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int array [ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5, 1, 2, 8, 12, 9, 0, 4, 52, 91 };
  int maxIndex = largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
  printf("%d", maxIndex);
}

// largest - function
// takes (array,length) -> returns the index of the largest element in the array

int largest(int array, int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
   int maxIndex;

   for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
   {
     if array[i] > array[i+1]
     i = maxIndex;  
   }

   return maxIndex; 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! `Main body` should be inside `main` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `largest` before `main`. Remove `ARRAY_SIZE` from its argument; you define `ARRAY_SIZE` as constant so you can't use this as parameter in function declaration.
And since you are passing array name to it and it will *decays to pointer to its first element*, you should declare it as

```
int largest(int *array, int n);
```

A `main` function is needed before your main body of program.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     int array [ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5, 1, 2, 8, 12, 9, 0, 4, 52, 91 };
     int maxIndex;
     maxIndex = largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
     printf("%d", maxIndex);
}
```

Also you should have to declare `i` and `index` in your `largest` function.
Your code after some fixes:

```
 // Program that finds the largest element in an array of integers

#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
// Main body
// Create and initialise a one-dimensional array of integers



int largest(int* array, int n);
int main()
{
     int array [ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5, 1, 2, 8, 12, 9, 0, 4, 52, 91 };
     int maxIndex ;
     maxIndex = largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
     printf("%d", maxIndex);
}
// largest - function
// takes (array,length) -> returns the index of the largest element in the array

int largest(int* array, int n)
{
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int max = array[0];

    for(int index = 1; index < n; index++)
    {
        if (max < array[index])
        {
            maxIndex = index;
            max = array[index];
        }

    }

    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it seems to be fixed. What exactly did you change apart from the int* ? Also, what's the deal with int*? I just started programming in C a few days ago and I'm pretty confused :)

Comment: I changed ` largest(int array, int ARRAY_SIZE);` to ` largest(int array, int n);` because you define `ARRAY_SIZE` as constant so you can't use this as parameter in function declaration. For `int *` read first line of my answer. Also I did some changes in your `largest` function---removed `i`, initialized `maxIndex` to `0`, changed ` if array[i] > array[i+1]` to `if (array[index-1] < array[index])`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your code isn't in any function. I think you just need a `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int array [ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5, 1, 2, 8, 12, 9, 0, 4, 52, 91 };
    int maxIndex;
    maxIndex = largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
    printf("%d", maxIndex);
}
```

I also added a declaration of `maxIndex` inside the `main` function, since the variable in `largest` won't be visible from `main`.

After your comment:

Your problem now is that `ARRAY_SIZE` is being changed to `10` by the preprocessor. Change your declaration of `largest` to:

```
int largest(int array, int asize);
```

Also change it below in the actual function.

Comment: Hi, I forgot about the main function. I've added it now but i'm still getting the errors :/

Answer (score 1):

C (and in particular, C99) needs to know about functions *before* they are called. There are two ways to do this:

1. Put your entire `largest` function before the `main` function.

   ```
   int largest(int *array, int size)
   {
       // ...
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Put a function *prototype* before the `main` function. A prototype is essentially a duplicate of the function's return type, name, and parameter list, e.g.:

   ```
   int largest(int *array, int size);

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       // ...
   }

   int largest(int *array, int size)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   With function prototypes, you can omit the names of the parameters, only the type information is important at that stage, so the function prototype can be shortened to just `int largest(int *, int);`.

Note that I changed two things about your `largest` function. The first parameter's type is now a *pointer* type. This is necessary when passing arrays as arguments to functions, essentially you are giving the function the address of the first element of an array. I also renamed the second parameter to `size`, because `ARRAY_SIZE` is a macro which expands to `10`, so the compiler is seeing this:

```
int largest(int array, int 10)
```

That's simply invalid C.

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thank you! Too bad I don't have the necessary rank to give you a thumbs up :(

Comment: @MichaelBlue: No problem! Some of the other answers only answered part of your problem, so I thought I would explain it all in one go!

Answer (score 0):

```
largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
printf("%d", maxIndex);
```

This could be an issue..did you mean to say

```
int maxIndex = largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
printf("%d", maxIndex);
```

??

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Mike!

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int array [ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5, 1, 2, 8, 12, 9, 0, 4, 52, 91 };
largest(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
printf("%d", maxIndex);

// largest - function
```

These operations, the `largest()` call and `printf()` call -- they can't happen here.  They're not legal syntax.  Functions must be invoked inside the declaration of an existing function.

Consider moving these into the scope of a function which should invoke these -- if at startup, you can make them early on in `main()`, or if this is a library, put it at the library's entry point.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks. I forgot about the main function completely. I just started programming in C a few days ago. Anyway, I'm still getting the errors and I'm not sure why.